# Razor Engine with layout page outside of a web project

Tags: c#, razor, class-library, layout-page

I am currently using the razor engine in a class library to render HTML for emails for an application.  This is working fine but as the number of email templates have gone up I would now like to implement master pages as well.  Is it possible to do this?  When I tried it, it gives me a null reference exception when parsing the view

Comment: wen project = web project?

Comment: Yes it does.  Sorry I have fixed that typo

Comment: Are you using the RazorEngine library?

Comment: Yes I am using the RazorEngine library that I added to my project through NuGet